# How can i get a total count of passes failures at the Project level in Cucumber JVM Reports for Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-plugins, cucumber-jvm

From the Jenkins dashboard I have Cucumber JVM for each job that's run. I can see my feature with for example 4 passed and 1 failed scenario.

In a particular tab (project/application/what have you) i'll have a series of features.

Is there a way to get a total count of passes/failures for the entire tab (all the features in the tab)? An additional plug in?

Answer (score 0):

Think this plugin should do the work:

https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting